# Wrong dependencies in IntelliJ when importing project from Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I have a project with compile dependencies on Swagger which brings jackson-databind v2.4.5 and a testCompile dependency on a library that makes use of AWS SDK which brings jackson-databind v2.6.6.

When running a test from gradle, everything works fine and the correct updated jackson dependency v2.6.6 is on classpath:

```
+--- io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.10
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.10
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.5 -> 2.6.6
|    |    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.12 -> 1.13
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.4.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.5 -> 2.6.6
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.5 -> 2.6.6
```

The intellij dependencies contain both versions:

[image: Both dependencies displayed]

However when running tests from IntelliJ, IntelliJ creates a "classpath jar" ( because the classpath is too long). When inspecting the classpath in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, I can see that only the smaller version jar (2.4.5) is included.

This causes an exception when the tests use the AWS SDK:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
```

Because the older jackson API did not contain this method.

Is this somehow preventable? I am currently using a workaround where I added the version 2.6.6 of the jackson-databind dependency in the testCompile dependencies. But I would like to avoid this, because

1. We are not using jackson directly, it's in the gradle script just because of intellij
2. every time the library that is using the AWS SDK changes, I'll have to change the jackson dependency as well

Note that we use IntelliJ test runner simply because it's faster than running tests through gradle on local workstations (mainly due to incremental compilation).

Answer (score 0):

Can't say, why IDE still has 2 versions of this library, though Gradle resolved dependencies. You can try to manually exclude transitive dependency on jackson-databind v2.4.5, something like this:

```
compile('io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.10') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
}
```

And then synchronize Gradle and IDEA projects.

Comment: I can't do this, if I exclude dependencies from compile, then the application won't work. If I run the production code, be it gradle or IntelliJ, there's only the v2.4.5.

Comment: Oh, I mean that you can add a newer version to your dependencies, if it works for testing. Or you can exclude newer version from testCompile dependency, if it won't break the build. Anyway, it's not ok, then your test and production dependencies differ.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now (see the question) - I am putting the correct version of the transitive dependency in the gradle script. I am looking for a way to avoid this because it's a hack.

Comment: I just see, that you've added newer version to test dependencies, but why don't you do it for compile? It's just the same as resolution strategy works in Gradle

Comment: I could do that. But I do not want to override transitive dependencies myself. I want IntelliJ to correctly resolve dependencies version (same way Gradle does it).